# Fastest way for collision detection with lists?

Tags: java

so i'm making a 2D game in java but I'm having some issues with the running speed of the game(it is pretty slow) and this is being caused by my collision detection methods, and I'm not quite sure how to correct it. So basically for collision detection for my enemies movement I'm using 2 lists(ArrayLists), one for my walls and one for my enemies(cause I don't enemies to collide). So my question is would it be more appropriate/faster if I used Maps instead of ArrayLists, or is it just my implementation that makes the game run slowly? Here is the code I have for the moment for my enemy movement and the ImageTile interface(if any complementary code is necessary feel free to say), thanks guys:

```
public interface ImageTile {

    String getName();
    Position getPosition();

}


public abstract class Enemy implements ImageTile {

    protected Position position;
    protected String name;
    protected int Damage;
    protected int Health;
    protected int Vision;

    public Enemy(Position position){
        this.position=position;
    }


    public abstract void move(Hero hero, List<Wall> walls, List<Enemy> enemies);

    public void loseHealth(int Damage){
        this.Health-=Damage;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return Damage;
    }

    public int getVision() {
        return Vision;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return Health;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}


public class Bat extends Enemy {    

    public Bat(Position position) {
        super(position);
        this.Damage=100;
        this.Health=150;
        this.Vision=5;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Bat";
    }

    @Override
    public void move(Hero hero, List<Wall> walls, List<Enemy> enemies){
        int x = hero.getPosition().getX();
        int y = hero.getPosition().getY();
        int x0 = position.getX();
        int y0 = position.getY();
        if((int) Math.sqrt((x0-x) * (x0-x) + (y0-y) * (y0-y))<Vision){
            if(x>x0 && y>y0){
                if(x0<9 && y0<9){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0+1,y0+1))) && !hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0+1,y0+1)))
                          x0++; y0++;
                    if(hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0+1,y0+1)))
                          hero.loseHealth(getDamage());
                }
            }
            if(x>x0 && y<y0){
                if(x0<9 && y0>1){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0+1,y0-1))) && !hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0+1,y0-1)))
                         x0++; y0--;
                    if(hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0+1,y0-1)))
                       hero.loseHealth(getDamage());
                }
            }
            if(x<x0 && y>y0){
                if(x0>1 && y0<9){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0-1,y0+1))) && !hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0-1,y0+1)))
                         x0--; y0++;
                    if(hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0-1,y0+1)))
                       hero.loseHealth(getDamage());
                }
            }

            if(x<x0 && y<y0){
                if(x0>1 && y0>1){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0-1,y0-1))) && !hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0-1,y0-1)))
                         x0--; y0--;
                    if(hero.getPosition().equals(new Position(x0-1,y0-1)))
                       hero.loseHealth(getDamage());
                }
            }
            this.position=new Position(x0,y0);
        }else{
            Random random = new Random();
            int i=random.nextInt(4);
            if(i==0){
                if(x0>1){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0-1,y0))))
                        this.position=position.plus(Direction.LEFT.asVector());
                }
            }
            if(i==1){
                if(x0<9){
                   if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0+1,y0))))
                        this.position=position.plus(Direction.RIGHT.asVector());
                }
            }
            if(i==2){
                if(y0>1){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0,y0-1))))
                        this.position=position.plus(Direction.UP.asVector());
                }
            }
            if(i==3){
                if(y0<9){
                    if(!walls.contains(new Wall(new Position(x0,y0+1))))
                        this.position=position.plus(Direction.DOWN.asVector());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  Basically the idea is that if your player is in Room A, there's no need to check for collisions in Room B or C.  Divide your game into chunks, and only check for collisions where the player and an object is in the same chunk.

Comment: Yeah I know you can do it that way, or using rectangle collision as well, but I was trying to find the best way using lists. But thanks anyway.

Comment: a litter suggestion, you can pre calc Vision*Vision as SquareVision then no need to do Math.sqrt every time and just compare (x0-x) * (x0-x) + (y0-y) * (y0-y)) to SquareVision

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pre-initiate a grid. This would mean you have some pre-loading to do, but during runtime the processing is very fast.

Let's say your "world" has a size of 300 by 300, you could make a grid:

`byte[][] grid = new byte[100][100]`

Change this size for better/worse resolution, test performance etc.

Now before running the game, you fill the `grid` by setting a `1` for walls and everything else to `0`.

Your movable object(s) hold their own coordinate in the grid, e.g.:

```
Public class Enemy{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    //Or use Coordinate, whichever you prefer
}
```

Now when a movable object (enemies/player) wants to move, you can simply check if a collision would occur, for example:

```
//Move right
if (grid[enemy.getX()+1][enemy.getY()] == 1){
    //Cannot move
}
else {
    //Move right
    enemy.setX(enemy.getX()+1);
    //And whatever else you want to do
}
```

Hope this helps, might be a bit of a refactor though

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I will try using that method.